# What's this icon set called?

Tags: image-sprite

First of all: I'm totally not sure if I'm on the right site, if so, please forward me to the right one. I'm willing to remove it and post it to the right one.

---

I'm trying to find separate images of this sprite taken from phpMyAdmin:

[image]

If anyone know the name of these icons or even know a site for this, please tell me!

Comment: We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2930) for style identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have a specific name other than something like phpmyadmin icons...

You can find these icons in the theme folder for phpmyadmin.

You can find more themes also at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/themes/#all